# AdMob banner is not showing test ads on Android (Cocos2d-x)

Tags: java, android, admob

I have setup a AdMob account with a banner unit for my game. Riding the internet for tutorials on how to implement AdMob for Android with Cocos2d-x was easy, but now I'm facing a problem I can't seem to find a solution to.

My banner doesn't show up at the top of the screen, and I get these 3 messages in Logcat:

```
I/Ads(19290): Starting ad request.
W/Ads(19129): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 0
W/Ads(19129): Failed to load ad: 0
```

Which leads me to think that I implemented the banner code correctly but something else is error-ing out. Another bizarre observation: if I remove the permissions `INTERNET` and `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` from my Manifest, **the banner shows up** saying that I need to enable the permissions to see ads.

Here is the code I use to create the banner. I don't think there's something wrong with it, and the exception is not thrown as you can see from the log I copy-pasted above.

```java
private void adCreate() {

    adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId(AD_UNIT_ID); // In my code I set the real value from the AdMob website
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

    try {

        AdView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new AdView.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        relativeLayout.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);

        adView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        relativeLayout.addView(adView);
        addContentView(relativeLayout, rlp);

        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
        .addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXX") // In my code I set the real value I got from Logcat
        .build();

        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Ads", "AdMob Error: " + e);
    }

    // Setup AdListener
    adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

        public void onAdLoaded() {
            Log.i("Ads", "onAdLoaded");
            adView.bringToFront();
        }
    });
}
```

I don't know what's going on, I have even tried to archive my unit on the AdMob website and creating a new one to use as Ad Unit ID, to no avail.

Thanks!

EDIT: It seems that error 0 is 'internal error'. No clue what this points to or where the error could originate from.

Comment: Stupid question but have you verified that your phone/tablet has access to internet?

Comment: Yes, I'm connected to my Wifi and can browse the internet.

Answer (score 1):

I feel stupid now. I was testing on my friend's phone and unbeknownst to me he was using the AdAway rooted app, causing AdMob to receive invalid requests to 127.0.0.1. I disabled AdAway and everything seems to be working fine :)